# Extract and filter nested dictionary array using lambda

Tags: python, dictionary

Im new to python and Im looking for a lambda solution to extract a dictionary with a dictionary along with filtering selected keys.

Example: My input is like below

```
 {'executionInfos': [
    {
      'cancelRequested': False,
      'execution': {'runId': 22CXalf3g9xdl7kts45gaagL0SdEYMTqockoag4LaBDc=',
                   'workflowId': 'TestWf1'},
      'executionStatus': 'OPEN',
      'startTimestamp': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 25, 17, 1, 8, 585000, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
      'workflowType': {'name': 'Test',
                      'version': '1.0'}
    },
    {
      'cancelRequested': False,
      'execution': {'runId': 22NwIvCxrizJQescq7rLILHtMl9ktxj343DC7unUq2GK7M=',
                   'workflowId': TestWf2'},
      'executionStatus': 'OPEN',
      'startTimestamp': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 12, 14, 19, 13, 837000, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
      'workflowType': {'name': 'Test',
                      'version': 1.0'}
    }
  ]
}
```

Im want to get a array of dict where i can filter keys on each dict(executionStatus) and extract keys from sub dict (workflowId) as well

```
 {'executionInfos': [
    {
      'workflowId': 'TestWf1',
      'executionStatus': OPEN',
    },
    {
      'workflowId': 'TestWf2',
      'executionStatus': OPEN',
    }
  ]
}
```

I know it can be done with if else conditions and looping but want to know how can it be done using lambda/ or any one-two liners.  I tried below and dint work

```
KEYS_TO_FILTER = ['executionStatus','workflowId']
res2 = map(lambda attr: attr.keys(), response["executionInfos"])
res3 = filter(lambda attr: attr in KEYS_TO_FILTER, res2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a new vacant dictionary and then use list comprehension. Here is a solution without using lambda function :

```
d = {'executionInfos': [...]}
d_ = {}
d_['executionInfos'] = [{'workflowId' : k['execution']['workflowId'], 'executionStatus' : k['executionStatus']} for k in d['executionInfos']]
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
{'executionInfos': [
    {'workflowId': 'TestWf1', 'executionStatus': 'OPEN'}, 
    {'workflowId': 'TestWf2', 'executionStatus': 'OPEN'}]
}
```